# Send ajax request at a given interval after on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, this, settimeout

I am sending an ajax request when the user hit the search button in the following manner:

```
$('#search').on('click',function(){
                    $('#searchResponse').hide();
                    $('#searchResponse').html('<img src="assets/img/loading.gif">');
                    $('#searchResponse').show();
                    $.ajax({type:'POST',url:'assets/php/handler.php',data:$('#form').serialize(),success:function(response){
                        $('#searchResponse').html(response);
                    }});
                    return false;
                });
```

Everything is working fine but I want to have something like an automatic update after the above happens. This means I have to set up something like a timeout after the request is completed so the ajax is fired again. I've tried the following but with no success unfortunately:

```
$('#search').on('click',function(){
                    $('#searchResponse').hide();
                    $('#searchResponse').html('<img src="assets/img/loading.gif">');
                    $('#searchResponse').show();
                    $.ajax({type:'POST',url:'assets/php/handler.php',data:$('#form').serialize(),success:function(response){
                        $('#searchResponse').html(response);
                    },complete:function(){
                        setTimeout(this, 5000);
                    }});
                    return false;
                });
```

I guess that the selector isn't right but what alternative should I use to suits my needs? Any help of guidance is more than welcomed.

Comment: What is meant to happen after the timeout? You are providing `this` as the argument to `setTimeout`, which will be the Ajax context.

Comment: I need that after the first request, at an interval of 5 seconds, the same request to be send again. This will return another content which I want to replace the old one.

Comment: Wrap the ajax call in a reusable function and make use of the `promise` it returns. Example updated below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not providing a suitable method for the `setTimeout` call. `this` is the ajax context. As you want to call the same upload a second time after 5 seconds, try like this:

```
$('#search').on('click', function () {
    $('#searchResponse').hide();
    $('#searchResponse').html('<img src="assets/img/loading.gif">');
    $('#searchResponse').show();
    var doAjax = function () {
        // return the ajax promise
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'assets/php/handler.php',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                $('#searchResponse').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
    // Call once then again on success
    doAjax().done(function(){setTimeout(doAjax, 5000);});
    return false;
});
```

Notes: `jQuery.Ajax` returns a `deferred`'s `promise` that you can use to chain together functionality. Although promises are initially more confusing than say callbacks they are far more powerful and worth learning. You *will* change the way you write your code once you try them :)

**Side-issue:**

As `@Peter Herdenborg` points out, these three lines hiding and showing the response are not all required. The reason is that they all happen on the same render cycle, so you will not see a visual flash.

e.g. this:

```
    $('#searchResponse').html('<img src="assets/img/loading.gif">');
```

will do the same as this:

```
    $('#searchResponse').hide();
    $('#searchResponse').html('<img src="assets/img/loading.gif">');
    $('#searchResponse').show();
```

Comment: Nice solution. Got a phone call and didn't notice you had updated your answer before submitting my own.

Comment: @Peter Herdenborg: Thanks. The OP added more info in comment above, so had to rewrite to suit the actual problem :)

Comment: Agree promises seem intimidating, but I guess it's time for me to figure them out :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. It's the first time I work with promises, I was a little bit afraid of them because it can look overwhelming at the beginning. Also I want to provide my gratitude for @PeterHerdenborg regarding his guidance. :)

Comment: @MariusNV: `Ajax` promises are the best starting point. Creating your own functions, that return their own deferred promises, is when it starts to get complicated. Trust me, you will write better code this way :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I can see that I will be able to write better code but still I have a long way ahead of me before I could master this like you do :))

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract out the ajax bits to a function which either calls itself with a delay or that is simply called using setInterval(). I also don't see a point in hiding `#searchResponse` before changing its contents, so I've removed that and the related `.show()`.

```
$('#search').on('click',function(){
  $('#searchResponse').html('<img src="assets/img/loading.gif">');
  loadResults();
  setInterval(loadResults, 5000);
  return false;
});

function loadResults(){
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'assets/php/handler.php', 
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    success: function(response){
      $('#searchResponse').html(response);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Note: An initial call to `loadResults` is missing. The requirement is to call it once immediately, then again after 5 seconds.

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks for pointing that out! Updated answer. Might have been neater to make `loadResults()` call itself with `setTimeout()` on success, to avoid this clutter.

Comment: If you do that you may go recursive.

Comment: Thanks @TrueBlueAussie! Regarding recursion, how could that happen? `setTimeout()` returns immediately after scheduling its callback argument, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but if you have `loadResults` call `setTimeout` call `loadResults` again, when that completes it will call `setTimout` again and so on (going by the way you described it). Maybe I just misread your comment :) Add an example of that to your answer.